# MDI app Menu Shortcut keys getting swallowed when form with WPF ElementHost is active

Tags: wpf, winforms-interop

I have a **Winforms MDI** app, and my newest form is developed as a **WPF** `UserControl` hosted by a `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost`.

I have found that when the MDI child with the **WPF** content is active, it appears to be swallowing the keyboard shortcuts defined in the main menu of the application (`CTRL-F, CTRL-P, F3,` for example).  Is there a way to tell the **WPF** `usercontrol` to pass these keyboard events back up to the Winforms app so the menus get their keyboard shortcuts again?

Comment: Did you found any answer? i have the same problem and i found [http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=477587](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=477587)
but the information not useful enough to me
thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate although more specific to Ctrl+Tab shortcut key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933885/how-to-get-default-ctrltab-functionality-in-winforms-mdi-app-when-hosting-wpf-u